# How to display bar labels in HorizontalBarChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have a HorizontalBarChart from [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library (version v3.0.0-beta1) in which I display the monthly spending of the user's accounts.

So i implemented this method:

```
List<Account> accounts = getAccounts();

final ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
Float count = 0F;
for (Account account : accounts) {
    entries.add(new BarEntry(count++, new float[]{Float.valueOf(account.getBalance())}, account.getName()));
}

BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, " ");
dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS);
dataset.setValueTextSize(10F);

BarData data = new BarData(dataset);
horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.setData(data);
horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.setDescription("Gastos por conta neste mês!");

horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);


horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.setFitBars(true);
horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.setTouchEnabled(false);
```

And this is what i got:

[image: Generated report]

What i want is, beside every bar, put the description of the related account. I tried to do this in line 6 with the `account.getName()` but it didn't appear anywhere in the report.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and correct putting this code:

```
horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return entries.get((int) value).getData().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    XAxis xAxis = horizontalBarChartMonthlySpending.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```